# ensure code is running twice with condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have code which needs to do request to some server with token,
Sometimes you need to run the code **twice** to get the data. (the exact same code ) 
How can I ensure that the code will run **only twice and not recursively** ?

Most of the time in the **first run** I got http response 401 and the **second run give http 200**

This is the code

```
async function magt() {
let auth: any;
    try {
        auth = await getTokens();
        if (auth.runtime?.status == 200 && auth.application?.status == 200) {
        ...
        //run rest of the code


       } else {
            console.log("unable to fetch tokens")
            if (auth.response.status == 401) {
                console.log("Running for the second time to get valid token")
                await magt()
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("error occurred while fetching token: ", e)

    }
```

I want to make sure that if I got always 401, run the `magt()` func only twice, what is the best way to do it ?

is there a better way from some simple counter which is defined by global?

Comment: I'd say: don't call it recursively in the first place. Otherwise, you need to pass a parameter for whether to stop or not but if your recursion depth is always 2 calls, that's wasteful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about a simple for loop?

```
async function magt() {
  for (var attempt = 0; attempt < 2; attempt++) {
    try {
      let auth = await getTokens();
      if (auth.runtime?.status == 200 && auth.application?.status == 200) {
        return true;
      }
      console.log("Invalid auth response:", auth.response);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("error occurred while fetching token: ", e);
    }
  }
  throw new Error("All attempts at magt'ing failed miserably");
}

async function something() {
  await magt();
  //"run rest of the code"
}
```

Or, if you're feeling fancier, write a wrapper function for retrying async functions:

```
async function retrying(func, attempts) {
  for (let attempt = 0; attempt < attempts; attempt++) {
    try {
      return await func();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(func, "attempt", attempt, "failed:", err);
    }
  }
  throw new Error("retry failed");
}

async function checkToken() {
  const auth = await getTokens();
  if (auth.runtime?.status == 200 && auth.application?.status == 200) {
    return auth;
  }
  throw new Error("invalid auth response: " + auth.response);
}

async function magt() {
  const token = await retrying(checkToken, 2);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i'd like the second option

Answer (score 1):

```
async function magt(iterationLeft) {
    let auth: any;
    iterationLeft--;
    try {
        auth = await getTokens();
        if (auth.runtime?.status == 200 && auth.application?.status == 200) {
        ...
        //run rest of the code


       } else {
            console.log("unable to fetch tokens")
            if (auth.response.status == 401 && iterationLeft) {
                console.log("Running for the second time to get valid token")
                await magt(iterationLeft)
            }
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log("error occurred while fetching token: ", e)

    }
```

Calling with number of iteration as argument `magt(2);`